# How to join two SQL tables by extracting maximum numbers from one then into another?

Tags: sql, logic

As others have commented, I'm now going to add some code:

Imported tables

1. table3
   [Case No. is the primary key. Each report date shows one patient. Depending on if the patient is import or local, the cumulative column increases. You can see some days there are no cases so the date like 25/01/2020 is skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgvB7.png)
2. table2
   [Report date has no duplicate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j94aN.png)

Now, I want to join the tables. Example outcome here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRMFm.png)

The maximum cumulative of each date is joined into the new table. So although 26/01/2020 of table3 shows the increase from 6, 7, to 8, I only want the highest cumulative number there.

Thanks for letting me know how my previous query could be improved. Your opinion helps me a lot.

I have tried Gordon Linoff's by substituting the actual names (which I initially omitted because I thought they were ambiguous).

His code is as follows (I've upvoted):

```
SELECT t3.`Report date`,
        max(max(t3.cumulative_local)) over (order by t3.`Report date`),
        max(max(t3.cumulative_import)) over (order by t3.`Report date`)
from table3 t3 left join
    table2 t2
    using (`Report date`)
group by t2.`Report date`;
```

But I got an error

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'new.t3.Report date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Anyways I am now experimenting. Both answers helped. If you know how to fix 1055, let me know, or if you could propose another solution. Thanks

Comment: Provide a fiddle (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) with sample data and desired result with explanations.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result in tabular format which would help other to react fast.

Comment: *every date from March to August without repetition or missing date* Show the constraint which guarantees this. *every date here is covered by table1* The same. *The thing with cumulativeA and cumulativeB is they never increase at the same time. So only one changes at a time as you go down the table (by order of id), and only increment one at a time.* The same too.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: As others have said, at the very least give us some sample data. Either in the query if you can produce a small set to demonstrate it or in a fiddle if its too long. Then also add a required result. With that + your explanation we can probably figure it out. Without the sample data its just too much effort for us.

Comment: @TomC No problem. Thanks for your feedback. I've edited as you guys have suggested. It's MySQL.

Comment: That is not sample data, its pictures of sample data. You want to make it easy so someone can cut and paste it into their own test query, or run it directly in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation and window functions:

```
select t1.date,
       max(max(cumulativea)) over (order by t1.date),
       max(max(cumulativeb)) over (order by t1.date)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date
group by t1.date;
```

This returns the maximum values of the two columns up to each date, which is, I think, what you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have cumulA and cumulB on table1. I suppose it will be to store the Max cumulA and cumulB for each days.

You must first self-join table2 to find the Max for each date (with a GROUP BY date) :

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.date, cA
FROM t2
    JOIN (
        SELECT id, MAX(cumulA) AS cA, date AS d2
        FROM t2
        GROUP BY d2
    ) AS td
        ON t2.id=td.id
        AND t2.date=d2
ORDER BY t2.date
```

After, you join left table1 on result of self-join table2 to have each days.

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.date = t2.date ORDER BY t1.date
```

Here is the fusion of the 2 junctions :

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN (

  SELECT t2.id, t2.date, cA
  FROM t2
      JOIN (
          SELECT id, MAX(cumulA) AS cA, date AS d2
          FROM t2
          GROUP BY d2
      ) AS td
          ON t2.id=td.id
          AND t2.date=d2
  ORDER BY t2.date
  ) AS tt

ON t1.date = tt.date ORDER BY t1.date
```

You do the same for cumulB.
And after (I suppose), you INSERT INTO the result into table1.

I hope I answered your question.

Good continuation.

*_Teddy_*